# Add captcha code

Tags: c#, string

I was trying to make a register form for my project and I ran in the following problem:
I'm trying to add captcha code. I have 10 pictures with codes (e.g. "8otes") and I want to compare the input with the name of the pictures. Each picture has it's named by the code is drawn. This is a part of my code:

```
string captchaImg = "";
Random random = new Random();
captcha = random.Next(1, 11);
switch (captcha)
                {
                    case 1:
                        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "C:\\...\\8otes.png";
                        captchaImg = "8otes";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "C:\\...\\6faf3.png";
                        captchaImg = "6faf3";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "C:\\...\\06453.png";
                        captchaImg = "06453";
                        break;
                }
if (textBox6.Text != captchaImg)
   MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Captcha");
else
   //execute code
```

Comment: 1) What you are trying to do 2) what you have tried 3) what was the result 4) why this did not work for you. You have 1 and part of 2.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the input from textBox6 with the name of the picture. In the code above, the result is always "Incorrect Captcha"

Comment: Why is this tagged sql and shouldn't the number of case in the switch statement match the range of random.Next, that is 1-10?

Comment: Hello, Why would you use this kind of Captcha instead of an production ready library ? Also could you post more of the code the input and the output ?

Comment: I'm removing the SQL tag as the question isn't related to SQL at all.

Comment: Well, your random number goes from 1-11, but you're only checking 3 values.  For the other 8 values, `captchaImg` will be null.

Comment: This is only a part of the code. I did the same thing for the other pictures. However, textBox6.Text is never equal with captchaImg and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Guessing you haven't debugged yet. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging check your algorithm at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. The code and the picture change before checking if (textBox6.Text != captchaImg). All I have to do is to check if (textBox6.Text != captchaImg) before changing the picture and the value of captchaImg.